# Rails f.select trying to disable a dropdown from being changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to disable a dropdown from being updated on a form.

Currently i have this line in my form:

```
<%= f.select :permission, options_for_select([['Admin', 'admin'], ['Read Only', 'readonly'], ['Editable', 'editable']], {:disabled => @permissions_disabled}) %>
```

With my edit controller method containing:

```
@permissions_disabled = params[:id].to_i == current_user.id.to_i
p @permissions_disabled
```

I can clearly see in my log that 1@permissions_disabled1 is true, but when i edit the form, i can still select new values in the dropdown.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`select` accepts 5 parameters, the 4th one is a set of options for the helper. the 5th one is the html options like class and id.  I think you need to pass it to that

```
<%= f.select :permission, options_for_select([['Admin', 'admin'], ['Read Only', 'readonly'], ['Editable', 'editable']], {}, {:disabled => @permissions_disabled}) %>
```

UPDATE: didn't see the `options_for_select` in your code. you don't need that if you're using `select`, you'd only want to use that when you're using `select_tag`

```
<%= f.select :permission, [['admin', 'Admin'], ['readonly', 'Read Only'], ['editable', 'Editable']], {}, {:disabled => @permissions_disabled} %>
```

Comment: I had tried that previously and when i do, i get this error `wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)` on my f.select line.