# Rails how to use f.select with virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model that contains 2 booleans in the database - admin, and readonly. Basically this allows me to have 3 levels of access (readonly, editable, and admin).

I have a screen that allows admins to edit other users permissions. Instead of having 2 checkboxes for the boolean values of admin and readonly, i created a dropdown using f.select and i created a virtual attribute called "permission".

Everything works fine when saving a user as far as permissions go, the only thing is that when you go to the edit page for a particiular user, it does not load the page with the user's actual permission in the dropdown. It just loads the first value in the dropdown as the default value.

How can i make it so this dropdown shows the users actual permission when first loading the user edit page?

Here's my virtual attribute code for my User model:

```
# get the permission
    def permission
        if self.read_only
            @permission = 'readonly'
        elsif self.admin
            @permission = 'admin'
        else 
            @permission = 'editable'
        end
    end

    # Set the permission.
    def permission=(value)
        p "VALUE = #{value}"
        if value == 'readonly'
            self.read_only = true
            self.admin = false
            @permission = 'readonly'
        elsif value == 'admin'
            p "INSIDE admin"
            self.read_only = false
            p "before #{self.admin}"
            self.admin = true
            p "after #{self.admin}"
            @permission = 'admin'
        elsif value == 'editable'
            self.read_only = false
            self.admin = false
            @permission = 'editable'
        end
    end
```

and here's my f.select in my form view:

```
<%= f.select :permission, options_for_select([['Admin', 'admin'], ['Read Only', 'readonly'], ['Editable', 'editable']], {:disabled => @permissions_disabled}) %>
```

I tried using collection_select, but couldn't figure out how to populate the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as stated in [Rails f.select trying to disable a dropdown from being changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332620/rails-f-select-trying-to-disable-a-dropdown-from-being-changed/15332685), you dont need the `options_for_select`.  If you remove it and pass the fourth parameter a `selected` option, you should be set.

```
<%= f.select :permission, [['admin', 'Admin'], ['readonly', 'Read Only'], ['editable', 'Editable']], { selected: 'readonly' }, { disabled: @permissions_disabled } %>
```

but given the code above, even without the `selected` option, as long as f.object.permission returns the right value, you should be fine.

Comment: Ah yes by removing the `options_for_select` it had the selected value on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your last options hash: `:selected => @user.permission`

For example:

```
<%= f.select :permission, options_for_select([['Admin', 'admin'], ['Read Only', 'readonly'], ['Editable', 'editable']], {:disabled => @permissions_disabled, :selected => @user.permission}) %>
```